# Where is the error in this proof? (possibly bad surjection assumption)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Can you help me find the error in this proof? I have an idea of where it is, but want to check my reasoning (at the bottom).

The proposition is: Let G be an abelian group and A is any subgroup of G. Then $G \cong A \oplus G/A $. (but this is actually false.)

The proof for this where I am trying to find the error is:

Since G is abelian, A is a normal subgroup of G. Consider the function $h:G\oplus A \rightarrow G$ defined by $h((g,a)) = ga$. This function is clearly surjective. (*That is the part I think is wrong?)

(Rest of the proof):Furthermore, since G is abelian, $h((g_1,a_1)(g_2,a_2)) = h((g_1g_2,a_1a_2)) = g_1g_2a_1a_2 = h((g_1,a_1))h((g_2,a_2))$ so $h$ is a homomorphism. By isomorphism theorems, $(G\oplus A)/Ker(h) \cong G$. Since the kernel of $h$ is the subgroup $\{(a,a^{-1}) | a \in A\}$, this kernel is a subgroup of $(G \oplus A)$ and isomorphic to A. Two cosets of kernel of h are equal when $(g_1,a_1)Ker(h) = (g_2,a_2)Ker(h)$. $(g_2^{-1}g_1, a_2^{-1}a_1) \in Ker(h)$, so $g_2^{-1}g_1a_2^{-1}a_1 = 1$ so $g_2^{-1}g_1 \in A$ and $g_2A = g_1A$. This shows that the association $\phi:G/A\oplus A \rightarrow (G\oplus A)/Ker(h)$ defined by $\phi(gA,a) = (g,a)Ker(h)$ is a function (and also homomorphism and bijection). So we conclude the proposition.

---

*My reasoning for thinking the function is not surjective is I'm thinking of a situation where G = ($\mathbb{R}, *) $ and A = {0}. Then the function given would not be surjective because Image($h$) $\neq G$. Am I right here or does this part of the proof hold?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be surjective?  Take $a=e.$  In your example, I think you're thinking of multiplication, but $0$ is the *additive* identity.

Comment: I don't think $\phi$ is well-defined. It says that if follows from the previous sentence, but the previous sentence is not what is required. Try writing out what is needed for $\phi$ to be well-defined, and try to prove it, I think you will run into problems.

Comment: I'm with you through $g_2^{-1}g_1 a_2^{-1}a_1 = 1$, and I agree that this implies that $g_2 A = g_1 A$. But does the reverse implication necessarily hold? You need that in order for $\phi$ to be well-defined.

Comment: Side note on your example: $(\mathbb{R},*)$ isn't a group, but $(\mathbb{R}^\times, *)$ is. I think that is what you meant. In that case, $A = \{0\}$ is not a subgroup. $1$ is the identity element, not $0$. The function is definitely surjective as per saulspatz's comment.

Comment: Simply take a counterexample such as $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ and see where the proof fails.